# How to create a transparent gradient that fits together with color of the image?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'd like to create a gradient that picks the basic colors of an image and creates a fitting overlay gradient so it somewhat matches with the image.

Like on this website: https://www.themoviedb.org/tv/69050-riverdale

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `background-blend-mode` for this.

[**What is that?**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode)

Here's an example of background-blend-mode with the `screen` filter:

```css
body, html {
  height: 960px;
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #3EA8E2;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/OUzUdxe.jpg);
  background-size: 640px 960px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}

body:hover {
  background-blend-mode: normal;
}
```